# Combine two dataframes one above the other

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes and I want to put one above the other "with" column names of second as a row of the new dataframe. Column names are different and one dataframe has more columns.

For example:

```
mydf1 <- data.frame(V1=c(1:5), V2=c(21:25))

mydf1
  V1 V2
1  1 21
2  2 22
3  3 23
4  4 24
5  5 25

mydf2 <- data.frame(C1=c(1:10), C2=c(21:30),C3=c(41:50))

mydf2
C1 C2 C3
1   1 21 41
2   2 22 42
3   3 23 43
4   4 24 44
5   5 25 45
6   6 26 46
7   7 27 47
8   8 28 48
9   9 29 49
10 10 30 50
```

Result:

```
    mydf
   V1 V2
 1  1 21 NA
 2  2 22 NA
 3  3 23 NA
 4  4 24 NA
 5  5 25 NA
 6  C1 C2 C3
 7  1 21 41
 8  2 22 42
 9  3 23 43
10  4 24 44
11  5 25 45
12  6 26 46
13  7 27 47
14  8 28 48
15  9 29 49
16 10 30 50
```

I dont care if all numeric values treated like characters. 
Many thanks

Comment: I'm doing that because I want to export one large dataframe (tha contains several dataframes) in xls and many of large dataframes to multiple worksheets via RDCOMClient package. I managed only to combine the dataframes with write.table and "append=T" but I want also multiple worksheets. Thank you for your answers that was helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you tried with `write.table`, but that seems to me like the way to go.

I would create a function something like this:

```
myFun <- function(...) {
  L <- list(...)
  temp <- tempfile()
  maxCol <- max(vapply(L, ncol, 1L))
  lapply(L, function(x) 
    suppressWarnings(
      write.table(x, file = temp, row.names = FALSE,
                sep = ",", append = TRUE)))
  read.csv(temp, header = FALSE, fill = TRUE,
           col.names = paste0("New_", sequence(maxCol)),
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
```

Usage would then simply be:

```
myFun(mydf1, mydf2)
#    New_1 New_2 New_3
# 1     V1    V2      
# 2      1    21      
# 3      2    22      
# 4      3    23      
# 5      4    24      
# 6      5    25      
# 7     C1    C2    C3
# 8      1    21    41
# 9      2    22    42
# 10     3    23    43
# 11     4    24    44
# 12     5    25    45
# 13     6    26    46
# 14     7    27    47
# 15     8    28    48
# 16     9    29    49
# 17    10    30    50
```

The function is written such that you can specify more than two `data.frame`s as input:

```
mydf3 <- data.frame(matrix(1:8, ncol = 4))
myFun(mydf1, mydf2, mydf3)
#    New_1 New_2 New_3 New_4
# 1     V1    V2            
# 2      1    21            
# 3      2    22            
# 4      3    23            
# 5      4    24            
# 6      5    25            
# 7     C1    C2    C3      
# 8      1    21    41      
# 9      2    22    42      
# 10     3    23    43      
# 11     4    24    44      
# 12     5    25    45      
# 13     6    26    46      
# 14     7    27    47      
# 15     8    28    48      
# 16     9    29    49      
# 17    10    30    50      
# 18    X1    X2    X3    X4
# 19     1     3     5     7
# 20     2     4     6     8
```

Comment: Thank you very much that's exactly what I want!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily without any packages:

```
mydf1 <- data.frame(V1=c(1:5), V2=c(21:25))
mydf1[,3] <- NA
names(mydf1) <- c("one", "two", "three")
mydf2 <- data.frame(C1=c(1:10), C2=c(21:30),C3=c(41:50))
names <- t(as.data.frame(names(mydf2)))
names <- as.data.frame(names)
names(mydf2) <- c("one", "two", "three")
names(names) <- c("one", "two", "three")
mydf3 <- rbind(mydf1, names)
mydf4 <- rbind(mydf3, mydf2)

> mydf4
one two three
1    1  21  <NA>
2    2  22  <NA>
3    3  23  <NA>
4    4  24  <NA>
5    5  25  <NA>
6   C1  C2    C3
7    1  21    41
8    2  22    42
9    3  23    43
10   4  24    44
11   5  25    45
12   6  26    46
13   7  27    47
14   8  28    48
15   9  29    49
16  10  30    50
>
```

Of course, you can edit the `<- c("one", "two", "three")` to make the final column names whatever you'd like. For example:

```
> mydf1 <- data.frame(V1=c(1:5), V2=c(21:25))
> mydf1[,3] <- NA
> names(mydf1) <- c("V1", "V2", "NA")
> mydf2 <- data.frame(C1=c(1:10), C2=c(21:30),C3=c(41:50))
> names <- t(as.data.frame(names(mydf2)))
> names <- as.data.frame(names)
> names(mydf2) <- c("V1", "V2", "NA")
> names(names) <- c("V1", "V2", "NA")
> mydf3 <- rbind(mydf1, names)
> mydf4 <- rbind(mydf3, mydf2)
> row.names(mydf4) <- NULL
> mydf4
V1 V2   NA
1   1 21 <NA>
2   2 22 <NA>
3   3 23 <NA>
4   4 24 <NA>
5   5 25 <NA>
6  C1 C2   C3
7   1 21   41
8   2 22   42
9   3 23   43
10  4 24   44
11  5 25   45
12  6 26   46
13  7 27   47
14  8 28   48
15  9 29   49
16 10 30   50
```

If you need to resort a package for any reason when scaling this up to your real use case, then try `melt` from `reshape2` or the package `plyr`. However, use of a package shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach with the `rbind.fill` function (part of the `plyr` package).

```
library(plyr)
setNames(rbind.fill(setNames(mydf1, names(mydf2[seq(mydf1)])), 
                    rbind(names(mydf2), mydf2)), names(mydf1))

   V1 V2   NA
1   1 21 <NA>
2   2 22 <NA>
3   3 23 <NA>
4   4 24 <NA>
5   5 25 <NA>
6  C1 C2   C3
7   1 21   41
8   2 22   42
9   3 23   43
10  4 24   44
11  5 25   45
12  6 26   46
13  7 27   47
14  8 28   48
15  9 29   49
16 10 30   50
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.

Assign the column names from the second data set to a vector, and then replace the second set's names with the names from the first set.  Then create a list where the middle element is the vector you assigned. Now when you call `rbind`, it should be fine since everything is in the right order.

```
d1$V3 <- NA
nm <- names(d2)
names(d2) <- names(d1)
dc <- do.call(rbind, list(d1,nm,d2))
rownames(dc) <- NULL
dc
```